# Why Database connection Access denied for user?

Tags: mysql, database-connection

Create an web application in Visual studio first time, I am trying to access mysql database server hosted on Godaddy, The exception 'Access denied for user 'uspolo'@'IP Address'. I have created user for Database in Controlpanel with all rights/privileges, but when running in Package manager console Update-Database, any suggestion?

Godaddy\control panel\ MySQL Databases\ user have full access to database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  By "user", I believe it requires the username *and* the ip address.

Comment: @Sunny:  1.  check your web.config or appsettings.json contains correct user name and password.   2. Test your connection:
Try connecting to the GoDaddy MySQL database from your local machine using a MySQL client (such as MySQL Workbench) with the same credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be due to authentication if the credentials you provied are incorrect you can also be if you have insufficient permissions, the database may have security restrictions there may also be connectivity problems between client and server.